# Errors with chrome web driver for selenium in python virtualenv

Tags: python, selenium

I don't understand what I am doing wrong. Can anyone help? Trying to open just a simple website using a raspberry pi with Raspbian

```
#!/home/pi/Documents/Tiller/bin python2

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome("/home/pi/Documents/Tiller/bin/webdriver")
driver.get("www.tillerhq.com")
driver.quit()
```

here is the error i get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Tiller.py", line 6, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("/home/pi/Documents/Tiller/bin/webdriver")
  File "/home/pi/Documents/Tiller/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/home/pi/Documents/Tiller/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 76, in start
    stdin=PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 390, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1024, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error
```

Comment: `www.tillerhq.com` use proper url seems problem with it, something like `https://www.tillerhq.com`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use a chromedriver that is compiled for the right architecture (probably this https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/armhf/chromium-chromedriver/65.0.3325.181-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 in your case).

That error looks like you're trying to run a binary that isn't compiled for your operating system.

Comment: Thanks! This helped a lot!!!